# Sharepoint Online - Create a list of Document Libraries in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to setup a list to display all the document libraries in a given subsite. This list will be part of this subsite as well.

I've seen several references here in the forum where ppl use C# code to query the lists and document libraries, filter the results to get only the document libraries and then display those items. But I'm using Sharepoint Online and I don't see the way to add C# code to it, not even through SP Designer 2013.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can easily achieve this using JavaScript and REST API.

Comment: Do do you have more info about this? Maybe a sample code snippet? Thanks !

Comment: gsandorx: Check my answer.

Comment: Are you driving any actions from the list, such as workflow, or some other management function?  Of do you just need the list for a report type of function?

Comment: I actually need to present a list where one of the columns contain the listing of my current document libraries. Each library would be listed in a separate row. That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a Script Editor webpart into the page and paste below script inside it.

```
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="libraryList"><h2>Lists</h2><ul id='libraries'></ul></div>
<script language="javascript"> 

var siteUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101",
    type: "GET",    
    headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(d) {
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(d);

        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;

        for(i = 0; i < results.length;i++) {
            html += "<li><a href='" + siteUrl + results[i]["ParentWebUrl"]  + "'>" +  results[i]["Title"] + "</a></li>";
        }

        jQuery('#libraries').html(html)
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('failed loading lists');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I had to put <script language="javascript"> </script> Then I added the link to a hosted jQuery following this link http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/adding-jquery-to-sharepoint/

Here's what it shows: 

Title 
appdata 
Composed Looks 
Content type publishing error log 
Converted Forms 
Documents 
Form Templates 
List Template Gallery 
Master Page Gallery 
MicroFeed 
Project Policy Item List 
Site Assets 
Site Pages 
Solution Gallery 
Style Library 
TaxonomyHiddenList 
Theme Gallery 
User Information List 
Web Part Gallery 
wfpub 

It doesn't show the doc libraries though :-\

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I've been unable to get this to work in 2013.  I get the header that says "List", but it's not showing the libraries within the site.

Comment: I got it to work in 2013.  JS complains about an unintialised variable "html".  You need to add a "var html = ""; just before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone comes across this and can't get it to work:

Add a `$` before the filter in the URL - i.e. `/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101"` and the filter will apply.

It will include a few system document libraries, but otherwise shows just doc. libraries.

Also, be sure to include the subsite name in the URL prior to the `/_api` - e.g.
`https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/subsite/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 10`1

Comment: Probably have been better to edit original or post a complete correct answer.